# How to put one QMap into another QMap

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

Project should give as random number but that is not important, then that number of random find in first map and add into second map.

```
int rand = 2;
QPixmap pixmap1 = QPixmap (":/imag/sedam_one.jpg");
QPixmap pixmap2 = QPixmap (":/imag/gedam_one.jpg");
QPixmap pixmap3 = QPixmap (":/imag/tedam_one.jpg");
QMap<int, QPixmap> map;
map.insert(1, pixmap1);
map.insert(2, pixmap2);
map.insert(3, pixmap3);
QMap<int, QPixmap> myMap;
myMap.insert(map.key(rand), map.value(rand));
```

Comment: if "rand" isn't a valid key in "map" this will fail

Comment: Do you want to take key-value pairs randomly from one map and then put them into another? Is that your question?

Comment: What about `myMap.insert(rand, map.take(rand))` ? -> Providing that you make sure rand is a valid key first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be different based on the behavior you want when `rand` is not a valid key.

1. If you want to ignore the key if it is not there in `map`, you would use:

   ```
   if ( map.find(rand) != map.end() )
   {
     myMap.insert(map.key(rand), map.value(rand));
   }
   ```
2. If you want a default-constructed value when the key is not there map, you would not create the `if` check from the above code and simply use the code that you have:

   ```
   myMap.insert(map.key(rand), map.value(rand));
   ```

Comment: @mario, if you think your solution will be useful to SO, please post it as an answer. Otherwise, delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that:

```
  int rand = 2;
 QPixmap pixmap1 = QPixmap (":/imag/sedam_one.jpg");
 QPixmap pixmap2 = QPixmap (":/imag/gedam_one.jpg");
 QPixmap pixmap3 = QPixmap (":/imag/tedam_one.jpg");
 QMap<int, QPixmap> map;
 map.insert(1, pixmap1);
 map.insert(2, pixmap2);
 map.insert(3, pixmap3);
 QMap<int, QPixmap> myMap;
 myMap.insert(rand, map.value(rand));
```

Notice the last line.  `map.key(rand)` should be  just `rand`   because the method `map.key()` requires that you put in a value such as a QPixmap

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This will overwrite values. You can use a QMultiMap if you wish to have multiple keys.

```cpp
QMap<QString,QString> sneed;
QMap<QString,QString> feed;

QMapIterator<QString,QString> i_Map(feed);
while ( i_Map.hasNext() ) {
        i_Map.next();
        sneed.insert( i_Map.key(), i_Map.value() );
}
```